# Update-AzureRmEventGridSubscription setup subject prefix/postfix to string empty

Tags: powershell, azure-eventgrid

I have PowerShell script to update EventGrid subscriptions. One of possible scenarios is to set subscription subject prefix/postfix to define value.

```
Update-AzureRmEventGridSubscription -ResourceGroup $ResourceGroupName -TopicName $EventGridTopicName -EventSubscriptionName $Subscription.name -SubjectEndsWith $Subscription.subjectEndsWith
```

When value is not null or empty then it works fine. But when it needs to be set to '' it throws

```
 Cannot validate argument on parameter 'SubjectBeginsWith'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again
```

Should I recreate subscription?

Comment: I suspect you want to delete the "powerpoint" tag and add a "powershell" one.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be a bug in the Update-AzureRmEventGridSubscription implementation, thanks for reporting this! I have filed an issue at https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/6331 to track this issue.

Until this is fixed in the EventGrid PowerShell module, the workaround would be to:

1) Either delete and re-create the event-subscription, or

2) to use the equivalent command in Azure CLI (az eventgrid event-subscription update --resource-group your-rg-name --topic-name your-topic-name --name your-event-subscription-name --subject-ends-with "").